# Как сделать так, чтобы каждый раз вывод был с новой строки

Tags: python, строки, input, переменные, умножение

```
prasa = input ()

b = int (input ())

print (b * prasa)
```

Чтобы каждый раз переменная prasa выводилась с новой строки.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? У вас и так вывод происходит с новой строки

Comment: Cамое простое `input('\n')` но хорошим тоном является писать что именно ожидается на входе

Comment: print(*[prasa]*b, sep='\n')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассмотрим функцию print:
Она имеет аргументы `*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', flush=False`. flush и sep нам не важны. Аргумент end, обозначающий заключающие символы вывода, как было показано ранее по умолчанию имеет значение переноса строки (`\n`).
Поэтому, вам не нужно ничего делать для того, чтобы каждый новый print был с новой строки.

На всякий случай, если вам необходим вывод через строчку, то передавайте строчку  с переносом строки, вот так:

```py
print(prasa + '\n')
```

Возможно, вы неправильно сформулировали вопрос и вам нужен вывод с новой строки каждый раз. Тогда вам тоже ничего не нужно делать. Вводя значение, вы клавишей Enter сами переносите строку.

Зная то, что вы ввели еще одну переменную, вероятно то, что вам нужно несколько раз повторить prasa. В таком случае тоже все просто:

```py
print((prasa + '\n') * b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prasa = input ()

b = int (input ())

for i in range(b):
    print (prasa)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chislo = int(input())
print("Купи слона!\n" * chislo)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]